# call update action via link in email with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to activate a user who signs up by calling the update action in my ActivationController.

In my `activation.html.erb` file I have this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    To activate your account, please click the link below:

    <%= link_to "Click Here", activation_url(@user.activation_token), method: :put %>
  </body>
</html>
```

`rake routes` looks like this:

```
 activation PUT    /activations/:id(.:format)          activations#update
```

But when I click this link in the email I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/activations/icrvr5uNahnA5fpVjVTDEw"
```

help,

mike

**UPDATE**

Per the answer below I changed my route to this:

```
activations_validate GET  /activations/validate(.:format)  activations#validate
```

But now how am I supposed to grab the params[:id] from the URL when there is no :id in the route?

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file, try making it a GET instead of PUT, and change the method to something like `activations#validate` (change in your controller too, obviously), then in the validate method in the controller, check `params[:id]` against your validation logic, and if successful, update (activate) the user and reroute to where ever.

Comment: Thanks @theButler, but my rake route looks like so:
activations_validate GET     /activations/validate(.:format) activations#validate

How am I supposed to grab the params[:id] from that?

I understand how to grab it if the route looks like this:
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)           users#edit

Comment: like this: `match 'activations/:id' => 'activations#validate'`, but remember to put this after any other activations routes